# Sanity PatchEvent functions are not very clear on what they do

Tags: reactjs, sanity

I'm using sanity and trying to figure out what exactly the `set`, `unset`, `insert` functions do. As well there are methods on the `PatchEvent` class itself and I can't seem to find any documentation on that either.

For example I can see that `set` in the example takes one argument. But through more research of the code `set` actually takes two arguments, one being the `path` and the other being the `value`. It is unclear how path works and what it exactly does.

Since I am trying to update an object in array it looks like this is something I should be doing  as this is what is done in the default `ArrayInput`. I tried to make it work, but no errors and no updates are happening. This is what I have:

`PatchEvent.from(key ? set(key, [idx, '_key']) : unset())`

On top of all this I can see that there are methods directly on the `PatchEvent` that are also being used like `prefixAll`, `prepend`, and `append`. I more or less would just like some good documentation on all of this otherwise I might as well just stick with the HTTP Api and update/manage everything on my own for the custom components.

Comment: Having banged my head against the wall with the same issue, https://www.sanity.io/docs/studio-react-hooks#patch-f26a6c4e5e9b finally solved the problem when combined with `withDocument` from `part:@sanity/form-builder`. `const {patch} = useDocumentOperation(
    document._id.replace("drafts.", ""), document._type)` allowed me to update other fields in a custm input component. Where `document` is retrieved from props.